# Razor and Jquery for-loop

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem with Razor and Jquery in combination:

```
if (@min >= @customProperty.Count){    
    @for (int i = 0; i < min - customProperty.Count; i++)
        @:$('.customClass tr:last').after('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
}
```

I get a syntax error, what should be the right syntax?

Comment: Try @@ with your syntax

Comment: @Bharat Patidar, no sorry I get even more syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Block statements must be inclosed in "{" and "}""*

The `@for` starts a razor block statement, so you need:

```
if (@min >= @customProperty.Count){    
    @for (int i = 0; i < min - customProperty.Count; i++) 
    {
        @:$('.customClass tr:last').after('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
    }
}
```

---

As the js `if` is run using server side variables (ie will not change once rendered), you could make this a server-side `@if`, giving:

```
@if (min >= customProperty.Count)
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < min - customProperty.Count; i++)
    {
        @:$('.customClass tr:last').after('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `@:$('.ccuListView tr:last').after('<tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tr>');` Willl result in SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&''(inside of my console, FireFOx). What to do here ?

Comment: You're putting that in your browser console?   It's server-side code, not client-side.   Remove the "@:" for client-side.